# sendmail on linux not working

Tags: linux, email, terminal, sendmail

I have tried everything I can possibly find on the interwebs and nothing I do makes any difference at all. I am trying to send out email with sendmail on my linux box. The larger picture is I need to send off emails when a process fails or crashes on a node server, my company does not have smtp by choice, so I am looking into using sendmail through nodemailer. Needless to say it isn't working correctly. I am not getting an error, but the mail never goes through, so I decided to go more basic and just test sendmail through the terminal, and I can't get any mail to send at all. I have gone into the /etc/mail directory and edited both the sendmail.mc and submit.mc files to get a fully qualified domain name, I found a quick tutorial online that said to add the following to the sendmail.mc file...

```
Dmbar.com
define('confDOMAIN_NAME', '$w.$m')dnl
```

So I added that and then ran the 'sendmailconfig' command to update the app, then just to be safe I ran the '/etc/init.d/sendmail restart' command to restart the sendmail daemon. 
Then I run the sendmail command to test send an email like so...

```
sendmail -t < email.txt
```

Where the contents of email.txt are simply...

```
to:realemail@gmail.com
from:myemail@mydomain.com
subject: Test email

test test etst
```

yes the "realemail@gmail.com' is not where it was sent, there is a real email in that line, and the 'myemail@mydomain.com' is not what is in the file either, that is replaced with an actual email address.

Still no mail goes through. When I bring up the 'sendmail -bp' command I get things like...

```
 u4KJaAJF030710readqf*  -1   Fri May 20 12:36  <****@***********>
             (Deferred: Connection refused by alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.)
                 <realemail@gmail.com>
```

yes I replaced the sender with *****, but safe to say it is using computeruser@computername and not the from in the mail file, nor the DOMAIN_NAME that has been defined in the .mc file.

I am really lost here, nothing I do seems to matter, I can't get this to send an email and I really need this running. I have been scouring the internet all day and everything I find is either, add that define line in to the sendmail.mc file, or just simple commands on how to actually send the mail, I can't find anything that would help as to why this isn't sending any emails. I can, however, hop into a PHP page and successfully send an email with the "mail" PHP function just fine, so I know my system is able to send emails correctly. 
I am begging for any help at all, email is not my strong suit, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue finally. It turns out that Comcast does not allow any communications on port 25, so all of my emails are getting blocked. Pain in the ...!